# rebuild a vuejs (nodejs) module

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, node-modules

I am testing a module built for vuejs, but there is an annoying warning that I think I know how to solve (it's cited on its issues on github). I also tried with a console.log just to be sure.
I tried to correct it inside node_modules src directory but I fail to understand how to recompile it and use in my project. npm rebuild doesn't do anything and if I delete the "dist" directory of the module, nothing happens as well.

How could I do that? Should I wait and hope that the original author correct it? I'm just testing the module, I am not sure I am going to use it.

This is the repo: https://github.com/kamil-lip/bootstrap-vue-treeview

Comment: Why not go to the repo and make the changes and author might do a merge?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ because there is already an issue on that list and the last update was 2 years ago.

Comment: an issue and pushing a correction are two different things

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ First I'd like to test the correction myself before pushing it, thus my question. Second you are derailing the question, I was just answering you.